# NServicebus delay message saga?

Tags: nservicebus

How can I delay processing a saga message in NServicebus for 24 hours?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend holding on to the message data in your saga, request a timeout for 24 hours, and when your saga gets the timeout call, do your processing.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I put your answer to the test and it worked great. NServicebus has some really great features.